# use a three.js shader pass effect with fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, glsl, mesh, react-fiber

I would like to use this shader pass below in a react-fiber project :

https://github.com/felixturner/bad-tv-shader

how to convert this :

```
composer = new THREE.EffectComposer( renderer);
renderPass = new THREE.RenderPass( scene, camera );
badTVPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.BadTVShader );
composer.addPass( renderPass );
composer.addPass( badTVPass );
badTVPass.renderToScreen = true;
```

into react-fiber ?
Thanks.

Comment: did you find out?

Comment: I use this : https://github.com/pmndrs/react-postprocessing. Does it help ?